# TYPO3: Is there any way to use javascript inside Alt-Doc form?

Tags: php, javascript, content-management-system, typo3, typoscript

I want to know that is there any way to add own javascript code which will be execute in the form processing of Alt-Doc.php.

I need to change a selectbox value depend on other selectbox(select event).

Is it possible ??

Comment: Do you really need your own javascript code to do this? Wouldn't it be enough for you to use in-built functionality? That is 1. request for an user to reload the form upon changing of the field value + 2. conditional display of values in one field depending on the value in another field.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$TCA['tt_content']['ctrl']['requestUpdate'] = "yourfieldname"` to let TYPO3 add the js code (`onchange` event) to the given field. You can then write different palettes to yout TCA with different values. It's done this bay by tt_content (field `CType`) and also in the pages table (type sysfolder vs. "normal page").

The other form elements completely change in those two cases. Of course, this will cause a reload of the whole form, so you should place a field with this behavior at the top of the form.